# Vscode Unittests not discovered when using conda environment with mamba installed

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use tests in vscode. When I am on the default interpreter in /usr/bin/python3 I have no problem and my simple tests are discovered. However when I select the conda interpreter the tests disappear and if I configure the tests again they won't appear.

This is the python output when I try to discover tests on the conda env:
[image: screenshot]

When I take that command
`conda run -n uavsar --no-capture-output python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.3/pythonFiles/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.3/pythonFiles/testing_tools/unittest_discovery.py ./tests test*.py` and run it without the `--no-capture-output` in the vscode terminal I see results from my tests. I can also get the tests to be discovered with the conda env activated from the terminal with `python -m unittest discover`.

vscode version - 1.67.2
python version - most current (2022.6.3)

Any advice or thoughts?

Comment: provide some more details https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else finds this and has this problem

I had installed mamba directly into my conda environments instead of into the base environment and recreating those environments. The mamba installation instructions specifically warns against installing mamba into anywhere other than the base environment. [mamba installation docs](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

For some reason installing mamba into a pre-existing environment meant vscode would not find my tests. I deleted all my conda environments with mamba installed, installed mamba into the base environment and now vscode can find my tests.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a reason for mamba forcing you to install it in base environment. But in most cases, installing packages in base environment to avoid a test issue sounds dimishing the point of having conda environments...

I ran into the same issue but with other packages.

In my case, the issue is an open [VSCode bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4300). See the replies for workarounds that don't require you to stick to the base environment.

This works for me:

1. Activate the conda environment in command line and the also launch the VSCode from there.
2. Create a *launch.json* file in VSCode to tell the debugger to use the integrated terminal:

```json
 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, if you have Anaconda Navigate, you can launch the bundled VSCode in the correct environment from the UI. That should launch a VSCode that has everything already configured for the environment.